# Problem while rotating a 3D object with a rotating parent to face a given direction in Three.js

Tags: three.js, rotation

I am trying to plot an scene where there is an Earth that rotates independently from the camera. In this planet I plot random bezier curves just like in this example: https://pubnub.github.io/webgl-visualization/

Therefore, I add my bezier line as:

```
    var origin = latLonToVector3(lat_source, lon_source, earth_radius);
    var destination = latLonToVector3(lat_destination, lon_destination, earth_radius);
    var bezierline = bezierCurveBetween(origin, destination);
    earth.add(bezierline);
```

so that the plotted line rotates along with the Earth. Then, I managed to load a 3D model of a plane and make it follow the bezier curve as it is being drawn. So far so good. Finally, I would like to rotate the plane so that its belly is always following a tangent line to the bezier curve. To that end, I computed the tangent vectors for every two points of the line as:

```
    var tangent_vectors = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < pnts.length - 1; i++) {

            var aux = new THREE.Vector3();

            aux.subVectors(pnts[i+1], pnts[i]);

            tangent_vectors[i] = aux.normalize();

    }

return tangent_vectors;
```

Just to check that these vectors are ok, I used a `THREE.ArrowHelper` to see if they are tangent to every segment of the curve and indeed they are. Since I add them to the scene with `earth.add( arrowHelper );` they also rotate with the planet and are consistent. I repeat this process over and over as the planet rotates by plotting and erasing the same bezier curve (same origin and destination).

However, the 3D Model behaves fine for the first bezier curve but as the planet rotates and a new bezier curve is plotted at the same place (with the same origin and destination coordinates) I can see that the plane is still following (`plane.lookAt(tangent_vectors[point_index]);`) the tangent lines of the original bezier curve (even though I am recomputing the tangent lines).

I think that the problem is that latitudes and longitudes (`lat_source`, `lon_source`, etc) are fixed in the real life reference framework. This causes that `origin` and `destination` variables always return the same values even though the planet is rotating. Then, the new bezier curves have essentially the same points but since I add these points using `earth.add(bezier_line);` Three.js internally takes care of rotating them to position them in the new rotation and this is not done with my tangent vectors.

I think this is the problem, but I do not know how to solve it. I guess I need to also rotate the tangent vectos of the curve according to the new rotation but I can't find how to do it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: As far as I remember, `lookAt` doesn't work outside the world coordinate system--In other words, if an object's parent is transformed, then the object's `lookAt` may have unexpected results. Try converting your curve's vertices to world coordinates before performing any computations. ([`Object3D.localToWorld`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld))

Comment: lookAt was fixed around r95